# Why readline does not unset `backward-delete-char`?

Tags: readline, libreadline

I need to bind the code `127` (aka `DEL`, aka `^?`) to `delete-char`.

If I put `DEL: delete-char` to `~/.inputrc`, it does not work. This is because this code is used by `backward-delete-char` by default.

So, first I need to free this code from `backward-delete-char`:

```
$ bind -u backward-delete-char
```

But for some reason it is not unset:

```
$ bind -q backward-delete-char
backward-delete-char can be invoked via "\C-?".
```

What should be changed in source code of *readline* library (for local use) to unbind the `\C-?` from `backward-delete-char`?

**N.B.** If I unset for example `delete-char`, it works flawlessly:

```
$ bind -u delete-char
$ bind -q delete-char
delete-char is not bound to any keys.
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0)` I see the same thing. I am able to unset the one I wanted with this: `bind -m emacs-meta -u backward-kill-word`

According to the maintainer Chet:

> Unless you use the `-m' option, the commands act on the current keymap, which is either`emacs' or (usually) `vi-insert'

I found that his example commands didn't quite work, and only `-m emacs-meta` worked - but I'm not sure how to discover precisely which keymap applies.

Discovery process: searched the mailing list (Googled and `site:http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/ "bind -u"`) and picked up:
[Re: Some readline functions can't be unbound with bind -u](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-05/msg00083.html)

Comment: Note: I recently went back and tried this on `beginning-of-line`, but it wasn't working even with a variety of keymaps - so I ended up unbinding the key sequences one by one (e.g., `bind -r '\C-a'`)